# max size of char array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a max limit to the number of bytes you can allocate to an array pointer?

For example if i use a size of 16000 then this works.

```
char* iobuffer=new char(16000);
iobuffer[15000]='a';
```

However

```
char* iobuffer=new char(160000);
iobuffer[150000]='a';
```

this does not.

It shouldn't be a memory issue so is there some internal restriction?  After looking further it might be that the heap cannot store that much.

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not"?  What happens?  Also, what is the environment this program is running in?  Is it a typical PC? or perhaps an embedded app?

Comment: The max size that my cpu can handle is 536870911.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've actually got your allocation code wrong. You're using *parenthesis*, which provide an initializer for your newly allocated value. In other words, in both cases you have a *single* `char` allocated for use, initialized to `16000` and `160000` respectively. Use *brackets* to dynamically allocate an array.†

After that, you subscript (*way*) out of bounds, leading to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). (Any subscript past zero in your case is undefined behavior; more generally, subscripting past array bounds is undefined behavior.)

To answer the question, there is no limit, language-wise. It depends on your running environment.

---

†Of course, you should never use `new[]`. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Then why does the first case work?  Surely 15000 is out of bounds for a size 1 array...

Comment: It doesn't "work". It's undefined behavior. You simply got lucky. (Or, one could argue unlucky as to you it seemed it was working)

Comment: I bet if you turn on optimization (pass `-O2` to GCC), the first case won't work any more. `-O0` seems to give bad programming a lot of slack.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the limit is the largest block available on the heap. It's not a constant number, even throughout the execution of your program it changes.

That is why, you **must** always verify that the memory was allocated. After each `new` check the result for null pointer and catch exceptions, if those are enabled.

All that regardless of the mistakes in your code which were pointed out already, and the valid suggestion to use `std::vector` instead of directly allocating arrays.

Comment: `new` will never return null in C++.

Comment: Except in some special cases like really old compilers and strange embedded environments, `operator new` will never return null unless you use `std::nothrow`.  I hate seeing code cluttered with null checks that can never be triggered.  --  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.6

Comment: Well, forgive me for being used to some old compilers and embedded environments where we have exceptions disabled by default:-) Better safe than sorry, I say, but using `std::vector` instead solves the issue in a much better way anyway.

Comment: What happens when `std::vector` can't allocate memory and exceptions are disabled?  Do you get some "push back"? (sorry)  But seriously, does it crash the app, or do you have to check that the size of the vector actually increased every time you add something to it?  Both of those possibilities are just awful.

Comment: @Tim, `std::vector` provides random access, but it doesn't provide contiguous memory, so it can allocate more than one single chunk, and hide it from you. If you're totally out of memory, well then the app will crash or do some other undefined stuff, and we have to live with the fact that sometimes the behavior is undefined. If we're in an environment which must be deterministic at all times, then yes - you must check (but you'd probably do it through the `allocator` optional parameter of the `std::vector`).

Comment: @littleadv: `std::vector` guarantees a contiguous memory block just like any `new sometype[N]` returns. This allows you to, for example, pass `&(x[0])` to old C-style routines that want a pointer to allocated memory. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.3

Comment: @Seth thanks for the correction, but it doesn't really change the point.

Comment: @littleadv: So on your platform, running out of memory is a crash?

Comment: @GMan On my platform running out of memory triggers a reboot (all the allocators, including `new` are overloaded).